# How To Manually Redirect URLs To a New Blog

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I'm building my new blog on Tumblr, I've already got all my old WordPress posts and migrated them to their new home. The problem is that the Tumblr permalinks are different from the WordPress ones (the post title part), so I want to know how I can manually redirect URLs like:

> http://dreamintech.net/2012/3/post-title-something-test

To:

> http://nathancampos.me/post/1920418430/post-title-here

Is there any way I can do this without having to use `regex` to insert the `post-title` part on the new URL, because I want to make this all manually.

*PS: I don't care about the time it will take*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just make a map of the from and to URLs in your `httpd.conf` file like so;

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName dreamintech.net
 ServerAlias www.dreamintech.net
 ....

 # map relative URLs under dreamintech.net to the 
 # remote URL with a 302 redirect
 Redirect permanent /2012/3/post-title-something-test http://nathancampos.me/post/1920418430/post-title-here
 Redirect permanent /2012/3/post-title-something-2 http://nathancampos.me/post/1920418430/post-title-2
 Redirect permanent /2012/3/post-title-something-3 http://nathancampos.me/post/1920418430/post-title-3


 </VirtualHost>
```